# if exists(":command") fails on startup, using Pathogen

Tags: vim

I'm using `exists()` to check if plugins are installed in Vim (I mapped `;` to `:`):

```
if exists(":NERDTree")
    map <F4> ;NERDTreeToggle<CR>
endif
```

The mapping doesn't work unless I source the .vimrc file manually. I'm using [Pathogen](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2332) to load my plugins on startup, I imagine that has something to do with it?

My complete .vimrc file: https://github.com/ElbertF/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc

Comment: You should use `nnoremap <F4> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>` (no need to change a colon here + you probably do not want to call NERDTreeToggle in visual and operator-pending modes), not `map ...`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your call to `exists()` doesn't work because plugins are only loaded *after* vim has finished processing your `.vimrc` - see `:help startup`. Also, pathogen doesn't actually load your plugins, it merely adds their containing folders to the `runtimepath` option so they will be loaded after your `.vimrc`.

You could create a VimEnter autocmd to set up your mapping after vim has finished loading:

```
autocmd VimEnter * if exists(":NERDTree") | exe "map <F4> ;NERDTreeToggle\<CR>" | endif
```

Comment: Thanks! I stuck the whole section in a function and call it on VimEnter. `autocmd VimEnter * :call Plugins()`

Comment: Note: you could use `:scriptnames` to see that effectively the vimrc configuration file is loaded before plugins.

Comment: Details for writing your own `vim` function are covered here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Write_your_own_Vim_function

Comment: Will this still work with lazy loaded plugins?  If a plugin is lazy loaded based on filetype, will another `VimEnter` event be triggered?

Answer (score 3):

In the **MacVim** you can define some mappings in the `.gvimrc` file, which parsed after the `.vimrc`. It is useful to redefine GUI Menu commands such as *File → Open...* or *File → Save*.
Here is example of the `.gvimrc` file which redefines <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> hotkey to open NERDTree:

```
if has('gui_running')
    if exists(':NERDTree')
        " Command+O shows the NERDTree instead of the open dialog
        macm File.Open\.\.\. key=<nop>
        nnoremap <D-o> :NERDTree<CR>
        inoremap <D-o> <Esc>:NERDTree<CR>
        vnoremap <D-o> <Esc>:NERDTree<CR>
    endif
endif
```

Where `macm File.Open\.\.\. key=<nop>` command unbinds any hotkey from the menu item *File → Open*.
And `?noremap <D-o> ...` commands binds <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to show the NERDTree in the normal/insert/visual modes.